# React Highcharts change border color on selected column from local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have a react highcharts bar chart and a table showing the same data, and I'm trying to display the same selected item in both components. So when a row is highlighted in the table, the corresponding column should change border color.

I've manage to get the table to update from a click event in the chart by setting the state like this

```
const plotOptions = {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        click: e => this.setState({selectedColumn: e.point.x})
      }
    }
  }
}

<HighchartsChart plotOptions={plotOptions}>
...
</HighchartsChart >
```

but I don't know how to update the chart with the state property.

I've tried looking for [selected](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.states.select) properties in the  in the highchart docs, but I haven't found anything that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to and use `select` method on point which is related to clicked tabble cell. Please take a look at the example below:

```
handleClick(e) {
  let index = Number(e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
  this.setState({ index: index });
  this.chart.series[0].points[index].select();
}
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/61zx86993